# Вывод по 3 строки в JList

Tags: java, java-8, java-9

подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать эту функцию "Выведите название всех файлов, которые находятся в папке «Мои документы». При этом необходимо выводить список по частям. По три строчки. Предлагая пользователю ввести ENTER для продолжения (код клавиши равен #13)."

Я не знаю как сделать вывод по 3 строки, у меня выводится весь каталог в JList по нажатию JBtn

```
package LR3;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;

public class formProg1 {
    File pathDir = null;
    String[] pathsFilesAndDir;
    formProg1(){
        JFrame jfrm1 = new JFrame("Каталог");
        jfrm1.setSize(400, 400);
        jfrm1.setLayout(null);
        jfrm1.setVisible(true);
        jfrm1.setResizable(false);
        jfrm1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton jbtn1 = new JButton("Enter");
        jbtn1.setBounds(150, 320, 100, 30);
        jfrm1.add(jbtn1);

        DefaultListModel<String> list = new DefaultListModel< >();
        JList<String> b = new JList< >(list);
        b.setBounds(0,0,380,300);
        b.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jfrm1.add(b);

        JScrollPane jsp1 = new JScrollPane();
        jsp1.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 300 );
        jsp1.setViewportView(b);
        jfrm1.add(jsp1);

        JLabel jl = new JLabel();
        jl.setBounds(10,320,100,20);

        jfrm1.add(jl);


        //События
        jbtn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int n = 0;
                try {
                    // Создание нового объекта file
                    pathDir = new File("/home/atlas/"); // Обязательно должен существовать указанный каталог на диске, иначе программа выдаст ошибку
                    // Массив файлов и папок
                    pathsFilesAndDir = pathDir.list();
                    for(String path:pathsFilesAndDir) {
                        // Вывод списка файлов и каталогов
                        list.addElement(("№" + n++) + " " + path);

                    }
                }catch(Exception a) {
                    // Если произошла ошибка
                    a.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
               SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new formProg1();
                        new DefaultListModel();
                        new JScrollPane();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю зачем так нужно, но приблизительно так (далеко не идеально, как вы понимаете):

```
package stackOverflow.formProg1;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;

public class formProg1 {
    File pathDir = null;
    String[] pathsFilesAndDir;
    static int n = 0;

    formProg1(){
        JFrame jfrm1 = new JFrame("Каталог");
        jfrm1.setSize(400, 400);
        jfrm1.setLayout(null);
        jfrm1.setVisible(true);
        jfrm1.setResizable(false);
        jfrm1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton jbtn1 = new JButton("Enter");
        jbtn1.setBounds(150, 320, 100, 30);
        jfrm1.add(jbtn1);

        DefaultListModel<String> list = new DefaultListModel< >();
        JList<String> b = new JList< >(list);
        b.setBounds(0,0,380,300);
        b.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jfrm1.add(b);

        JScrollPane jsp1 = new JScrollPane();
        jsp1.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 300 );
        jsp1.setViewportView(b);
        jfrm1.add(jsp1);

        JLabel jl = new JLabel();
        jl.setBounds(10,320,100,20);

        jfrm1.add(jl);

        // Создание нового объекта file
        pathDir = new File("/home/atlas/"); // Обязательно должен существовать указанный каталог на диске, иначе программа выдаст ошибку
        // Массив файлов и папок
        pathsFilesAndDir = pathDir.list();

        //События
        jbtn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    if (n < pathsFilesAndDir.length) {
                        // Вывод списка файлов и каталогов
                        list.addElement(("№" + n) + " " + pathsFilesAndDir[n]);
                        n++;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new formProg1();
                        new DefaultListModel();
                        new JScrollPane();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, если бы я сам знал, зачем это нужно...